# How to upgrade openSUSE 11.1 to openSUSE 11.2

Tags: linux, upgrade, opensuse, opensuse-11.2

openSUSE 11.2 is going to be released in less than 2 weeks. RC2 is available for testing.

How can I upgrade a running openSUSE system to the next release? Is it possible without a complete reinstall?

Answer (score 3):

openSUSE 11.2 is the first release that will officially support live upgrade. The draft of the instructions is on the [wiki](http://en.opensuse.org/Upgrade/11.2)

Comment: you seem to have answered your own question here... is there something more you're looking to learn?

Comment: @pbr: no, thanks. I've found what I was looking faster than superuser community at large. That's it.